# Обновление коллекции источника данных Datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

На форме есть 2 грида. `DataContext` для формы - отдельный класс(ViewModel). Первый грид сразу заполняется данными(в конструкторе класса). При щелчке на строку этого грида должен заполниться второй. Вот разметка второго :

```
<DataGrid MinHeight="140" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,220,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding  TotalInvestCollectionByu, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowBackground="#FFD8C096"  >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Title}">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Isin" MinWidth="50" Binding="{Binding Isin}">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" MinWidth="50" Binding="{Binding Date}">
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

источник данных TotalInvestCollectionByu является публичным свойством класса ViewModel:

```
public static ObservableCollection<TotalInvest> TotalInvestCollectionByu { get; set; }
public class TotalInvest
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Isin { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
    }
```

И есть команда которая срабатывает при выборе строки первого грида. Коммадна по идеи должна вызывать заполнение TotalInvestCollectionByu данными :

```
    public ICommand SelectDetails
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(() =>
            {
                TotalInvestCollectionByu = new ObservableCollection<TotalInvest>();
                TotalInvestCollectionByu.Add(new TotalInvest() { Title ="newTitle", Isin ="newisin", Date ="now"});
            }); }
    }
```

Однако происходит так, что в коллекцию TotalInvestCollectionByu новые значения хотя и добавляются, в самом гриде не отображаются. как это исправить ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что что вы заменяете коллекцию в `TotalInvestCollectionByu` на новый объект. `ObservableCollection` даёт нотификации об изменении *внутри* коллекции (то есть, списка элементов), но об подмене объекта этой самой коллекции сообщить, понятно, не может никак. Поэтому ваш `DataGrid` продолжает наблюдать за *старым* экземпляром коллекции, в котором уже, очевидно, ничего не меняется.

Ваш VM-класс должен имплементировать `INotifyPropertyChanged`, и отправлять `NotifyPropertyChanged` в сеттере `TotalInvestCollectionByu`. В качестве альтернативы, вы можете просто никогда не менять `TotalInvestCollectionByu`, а очищать её при помощи `.Clear()`.

Comment: странно я думал в `MvvM light`  прописывать имплементацию `INotifyPropertyChanged` не нужно

Comment: если использовать только `Clear()` то ошибка  `ссылка на обьект не указывает на экземпляр обьекта`

Comment: @Сергей: Чудес не бывает. INPC всё равно надо как-то прописывать. Например, как здесь: http://doc.postsharp.net/inotifypropertychanged-mvvmlight

Comment: @Сергей: Ну в конструкторе-то надо один раз присвоить, понятно, а то откуда ж там возьмётся объект?

Comment: Вы правы, тормознул немного. Добавил обьект в конструктор класса - заполнение пошло. для полного счастья осталось только получить значение ячейки из первого грида но это уже совсем другой вопрос. спасибо!

Comment: @Сергей: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло!